# Capturing and decrypting my own SSL traffic

Tags: tls, sniffer

When I use browser or wget to access another site, some sites will only use HTTPS / SSL automatically. When a site doesn't provide content without encryption, how do I capture what my computer sends for analysis? Is it possible for me to disable SSL with my browser or wget?

I'm running Linux, and would like to use tcpdump or other Linux tools for this.

Answer (score 8):

Tools such as this [SSL MITM proxy](http://crypto.stanford.edu/ssl-mitm/) from Stanford can automatically generate certificates and provide an SSL-to-SSL cutover. You'll need to set the key used by the proxy to be trusted by your browser, but that will provide you with the ability to see the cleartext traffic that is leaving from your machine.

While you can try to rewrite any HTTPS redirect requests to have HTTP, many website that provide HTTPS support will only provide content over the encrypted channel; the unencrypted channel provides nothing but redirects.

Moxie Marlinspike's [SSL Strip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) will probably also fulfill your goal by transiting the HTTPS traffic, but only speaking with your client using HTTP and rewriting redirects.

Comment: I got the Stanford proxy to work using `java -cp iaik_jce.jar:. mitm.MITMProxyServer -localPort 8888 -keyStore FakeCAStore -keyStorePassword passphrase` after quite some tinkering.

Comment: I've got the mitm-proxy running, but it never gets a connection... it always crashes with javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Windows, try using Fiddler2.   It has an SSL proxy that will strip SSL for you so that you can see the packets going to and from your machine.

Comment: I'm on linux and I want to use tcpdump or other tools to capture the packets

Comment: Wenzi- I have added that into the question as that will *really* help people answer you.

Answer (score 0):

when you browse to http://plus.coogle.com - it responds with a HTTP 301 response "moved permanently" and redirects to https://plus.google.com

If you use an intercept proxy, use an environment variable to set the proxy name and set proxy parameters on the wget cmdline.