# Router level SSL Inspection

Tags: tls, network, man-in-the-middle, certificate-pinning

Is there any way I could inspect the traffic from an untrusted device connected to my network? I would like to get a router that has ssl inspection capabilities, where I could check the https packets sent through it, to check if cheap devices I have pose privacy or security risks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sniffing From Squid SSL](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41987/sniffing-from-squid-ssl)

Comment: Or [*Is SSL Interception possible without disabling Public Key Pinning on the client side?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129266/is-ssl-interception-possible-without-disabling-public-key-pinning-on-the-client) or [*Capturing and decrypting my own traffic*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25650/capturing-and-decrypting-my-own-ssl-traffic)... there's a *lot* of questions about TLS bump in the wire. In short - a router can't do it. Routers operate on L3. A TLS proxy can do it.

Comment: Are you trying to see the plaintext of the TLS-encrypted requests and responses?  If so, you will need to use something like [mitmproxy in transparent mode](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/) to MITM the connection, but this will require the client to accept a fake SSL certificate.  If not, a tool like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) will allow you to inspect the SSL packets to/from the client.

Comment: You could also somehow capture the keys and then PCAPNG/PCAP file from Wireshark would get decrypted.